# Query Exception when creating a database record using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am encountering a weird error.
In a laravel project I am reading a CSV file. In my **Controller** I am **parsing the CSV** and creating database records for a **mysql database**.
I convert the CSV lines into individual arrays which are located within a big array -> two dimensional array. So far so good.
When iterating through my array the first iteration works just fine and I get the database records as expected. However, during the second iteration a Query Exception is thrown.
The stack trace leads me to a line where I am assigning a double value to an attribute of the model.

```
          Transaction::firstOrCreate([
            'date' => $date,
            'transaction_type' => $the_big_array[$i][2],
            'db_counter_party_id' => $db_counter_party_id,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => $the_big_array[$i][6],
            'usage' => $the_big_array[$i][7],
            'category' => "none",
            'balance' => $balance_after_transaction,
          ]);
```

The last assignment is causing the error. The variable **balance_after_transaction** is of type double and calculated according to previous transactions. So it is not directly retrieved from the CSV.
Does someone have a clue what is going on?

Comment: Which exact query exception? What does the message say?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Comment: The message is the important bit. What is it saying is wrong with the query?

Comment: The message does not say anything else

Comment: That's funny. The exception does not have a message in the stack trace?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. Do you think it is a connection issue? Some error not located in the code?

Comment: \src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678

Comment: Does this indicate a connection problem?

Comment: Possibly. Not sure. Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Version 8. But why does the first iteration work then?

Comment: Not a connection issue, that line is inside the method that runs the query. Try dumping values throughout the stack trace, see if anything catches your eye.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! What do you mean by dumping values throughout the stack trace? To try different inputs? When I e.g. replace $balance_after_transaction with just "0", it gives me the same error.

Comment: No, I mean dump the values inside all the method calls that the error stack trace shows. Try and see where exactly something is passed that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by a wrong character encoding.